# Cannot perform POST request in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a form in a page that uploads user data onto my online server using the CodeIgniter framework. I can access the form page normally using the HTTPS protocol, but when I try to submit the form using POST, I am given a `403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access <url> on this server.` error. What could be the issue?

The `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My form attributes in the view. The `$base_url` variable is the `base_url()` configured in `config.php`:

```
<form name="new_article_form" id="new_article_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $base_url; ?>entries/insert_article" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
...
</form>
```

Am I missing something?

Edit:
The full form as requested. It does not use the form_helper from CI for now. Currently working on that:

```
<form name="new_article_form" id="new_article_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $base_url; ?>entries/insert_article" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

    <p>Blog Name:</p>
    <select name="blog" id="blog" required>
    <?php
    echo $blogs; //pre-formatted <option> list from controller
    ?>
    </select>
    <p>Article Title:</p>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required />

    <p>Article Author:</p>
    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="Own" required />

    <p>Authoring Date:</p>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="auth_date" id="auth_date" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y"); ?>" required />

    <p>Article URL:</p>
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" required />
    <p>Summary:</p>
    <textarea name="summary" id="summary" style="resize:none" class="text" rows="10" cols="40" required ></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button name="reset" id="reset" type="reset">Clear</button>&nbsp;
    <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">ADD</button>
</form>
```

UPDATE:

I just rewrote the whole form using CI's form helper lib, and am still getting the same error. The form request is not even getting to the controller nor the main index.php file, it is being terminated before that as no POST data reaches the main index.php file at the root of the framework. So this may be a permissions issue or something else before that. NB: am on a shared website hosting platform just in case anyone's wondering, and am currently using a self-signed certificate for online SSL testing.

UPDATE 2:

routes.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';

/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

config.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['base_url'] = 'https://<***full_url***>/';
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'BG_';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = '************';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = '*************';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 3600;
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';

$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

$config['proxy_ips'] = '';

/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/config.php */
```

entries controller:

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Entries extends CI_Controller 
{
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model("entries_model", "entries");
    }

    public function index($data = array())
    {

        ...//other code

        $form_attrs = array("name"=>"new_article_form", "id"=>"new_article_form", "enctype"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        $form = form_open(base_url()."entries/insert_article", $form_attrs);

        //... form entries

        $form .= form_close();

        $data["form"] = $form;

        $this->load->view('entries_view', $data); //the form is displayed on the view properly, no errors present, exactly as shown above
    }

    public function insert_article()
    {
        $blogID = $this->input->post("blog");
        $title = mb_convert_encoding($this->input->post("title"), "UTF-8");

        //... other insert code

        $this->index($data);
    }

    public function blogs($result = "")
    {
        //... blogs view function
        $this->load->view('blogs_view', $data);
    }
}

    //... other code
?>
```

NB: From what I can conclude, the error is on the server side, as POST requests from the mobile app using the site are able to get through, but browser POST requests specifically with form data are not getting through. GET requests are getting through fine though. The only error visible is also on the server error logs stating that the "404.html" page cannot be found. Anyone know what could be refusing the connections on the server side?

UPDATE:

HTTP Headers:

```
Host: <***site***>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://<***site***>/entries/blogs
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ba4ce8f6cf3ebd19a443763fa8a187c0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Open your developer tools and check the network tab. I think your POST is working.

Comment: @GuyT i did that, but it showed a 403 forbidden error

Comment: @Peter Could you post the generated HTML form?

Comment: I want to ask, what is the accepted extension for MIME types "multipart/form-data" and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as I have just realized from the header output and some research, those types are not supported on my hosted server

Comment: navigate to host/index.php/entries/insert_article and insert an echo at the first line in the `insert_article` function. Are you using an .htaccess?

Comment: @GuyT thats what I did to test whether the controller function is being called. Turns out, my hosting does not support multipart/form-data enctype or application/x-www-form-urlencoded type either.

Comment: And now, even after enabling that support, the complete form still is not being POSTed.

Comment: Just saw your update. First of all remove to the certificate to terminate a step. Change your `insert_article` to `function insert_article(){print_r($_POST]);die;}` If you receive data from $_POST but not from $input->post() then the XSS or CSRF filter is removing the data.

Comment: Sorry! I see that you've answered the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`site_url`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) helper in your form action then check in your controller if it's posting or not.

```
<form name="new_article_form" id="new_article_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('entries/insert_article') ?>" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

Also don't forget to include url helper.

Comment: Using `site_url()` did not help, still getting the same error

Comment: my browser gives no error trace, just the error message, my server access logs show all access is being granted, and I can't find an error stack trace on CI logs either

Comment: @Peter did you check other post requests are working or not?

Comment: I just tried another POST request to the same controller but a different method/function and different view: same technique, using form helper, and it worked. Then I switched tabs to try the above page again, it failed. Now am not sure what is really going on here.

Comment: @Peter did you added any custom route

Comment: No, there are no custom routes, just the default controller route and 404 override route. BTW, I have an app which does POST requests to the app using the framework on every request, and they all go through. Only the above post to insert new stuff does not seem to work.

Comment: @Peter can you post your **`routes`** file & **`controllers`** file & **`config`** file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the data being submitted by the form was being detected as an XSS attack on the servers Mod Security Firewalls, that's why the requests were getting refused even before CI could be loaded. It has now been disabled on my domain specifically, and the submission now works. Hopefully, no more blocks from now on.

Comment: May I ask you why the server sees the request as an XSS attack? Do you not encode the data properly?

Comment: @GuyT am not sure either, since the form data was simple UTF-8 encoded text being submitted over a POST request, nothing special. From what I saw there were some special characters being checked for which were triggering a false positive e.g. semicolons and colons in the data I was posting